# How to display an account owner NAME instead of Owner.Id in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript-controller, track

Please, someone help me to display an Owner Name in LWC datatable instead of Owner Id. I have  this apex controller and js code

Controller

```
public with sharing class AccountLwcTableController {
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable = true)
    public static List<Account> getAccountList() {
        return [
                SELECT Name, Type, OwnerId, CreatedDate
                FROM Account
                WHERE Stripe_Sync_Completed__c = TRUE
        ];
    }
}
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import getAccountList from '@salesforce/apex/AccountLwcTableController.getAccountList';
export default class LightningDatatableLWCExample extends LightningElement {
    rowOffset = 0;
@track columns = [
        {
            label: 'Account name',
            fieldName: 'Name',
            type: 'text',
            sortable: true
        },
        {
            label: 'Type',
            fieldName: 'Type',
            type: 'text',
            sortable: true
        },
        {
            label: 'Owner',
            fieldName: 'AccountOwner',
            type: 'string',
            sortable: true
        },
        {
            label: 'Created Date',
            fieldName: 'CreatedDate',
            type: 'lookup',
            sortable: true
        }

    ];

@track error;
@track accList;
@wire(getAccountList)

    wiredAccounts({
                      error,
                      data
                  }) {
        if (data) {
            this.accList = data;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to query `Owner.Name` as Abhin said, then you have to add a property `AccountOwner` to your data in the wired method. You could leverage [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to loop over those records and return a new array, but since data returned by a wired method are immutable, you have to clone them, so I'm going to use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
columns = [
    {
        label: 'Account name',
        fieldName: 'Name',
        type: 'text',
        sortable: true
    },
    {
        label: 'Type',
        fieldName: 'Type',
        type: 'text',
        sortable: true
    },
    {
        label: 'Owner',
        fieldName: 'AccountOwner',
        type: 'string',
        sortable: true
    },
    {
        label: 'Created Date',
        fieldName: 'CreatedDate',
        type: 'lookup',
        sortable: true
    }
];

error;
accList;
@wire(getAccountList)
wiredAccounts({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
        this.accList = data.map((acc) => {
            const accWithOwner = {...acc}; // clone the original record
            accWithOwner.AccountOwner = acc.Owner.Name; // add the new property
            return accWithOwner;
        });
    } else if (error) {
        this.error = error;
    }
}
```

By the way, you don't need to track those variables, if they are used in the template they are [already reactive](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reactivity_fields).

Comment: Thanks a lot, RubenDG. Your answer is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

In the SOQL try using `Owner.Name`. It will help to return owner name from Salesforce and change your code according to display the data in LWC.

Example : `SELECT Name, Type, OwnerId, Owner.Name,  CreatedDate FROM Account`

Comment: I have tried to use this. But it didn't help me. I think that the problem is in this part of js { label: 'Owner', fieldName: 'OwnerName', type: 'text', sortable: true }